# Asp.net form losing css formatting

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm trying to integrate an html page(which already has lots of formatting, links to css files, .js files etc)  in to asp.net

The problem is that some of the styles used in the html refer to a form element, like this:

```
#Area form input[type="mytype"] {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

When I try to wrap this up in an asp.net page, it loses the formatting, because I need to put everything inside an asp.net 'form' with runat="server". The Css gets confused because it's now a form within and area within a form.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head> 
<body>
<form method="post" action="uitest.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTUxMTcwNzgxMGRk/FKLdutHp78brNcMIqdbHqG7TcPZ3FoZf+HMkhw=" />
</div>
    <div id="feature">

    <div  class="validate-form">
        <span class="icon"></span>

        <input class="required-email" type="email" placeholder="Email address">
        <button class="btn"><span>Apply now</span></button>
    </div>

    </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

What's the best way round this? Can I just rename 'form' to something else in the Css?

thanks

Comment: You should add your HTML source code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a nested form in a Web Forms app. If your CSS styles aren't being applied, your selector isn't targeting your elements properly or your selected has lower specificity than another selector with conflicting styles. `runat=server` has nothing to do with it, as that attribute is not actually rendered on the page.

Now, it appears you have an illegal type for your input. Based on your selector, you should have a structure something like:

```
<div id="Area">
  ...
   <form>
     ...
     <input type="mytype" /> //ILLEGAL!!
   </form>
</div>
```

Why do you have a `mytype` input? You should only be using valid types, like `text`. Change them, and then add this:

```
#Area form input[type="text"]{
     background-color:red !important; //This is just for testing, don't put into production!
}
```

If your inputs don't get a red background, then adjust to this:

```
form input[type="text"]{
     background-color:red !important; //This is just for testing, don't put into production!
}
```

If you are still having trouble, actually paste your source code (click View Source from your browser, not Visual Studio).

**UPDATE**

Why do you have `#Area` in your selector? There is not element in your markup with that ID. This selector will work:

```
 form input[type="email"]{ ... }
```

Comment: Good call about the 'type' - it's actually type=email, but I put in mytype just as a placeholder. I think you've answered the question though - it's the form within a form that's the problem.   The trouble is, I've inherited all this from somewhere else - my task is to slot an existing html page into asp.net, and that existing html has <form> elements.  Can I just do something like change the form to some other element, so it doesn't conflict with the asp.net form tag?

Comment: (I've posted some of the code from the browser in the question)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to be able to interact with the input elements in the page's code-behind file, it's perfectly acceptable to just use literal HTML controls in the page's markup.

Assuming, also, that you are allowed to tweak the CSS, you can remove `form` from your selectors, and then just make sure you copy everything into a `<div> ... </div>` with an `id="Area"` attribute.

**CSS:**

```
#Area input[type="whatever"] {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Area">
  ...

  <!-- add markup here -->

  ...
</div>
```